# iOS Wild card profile for Appium Automation on a Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, appium, provisioning-profile, ios-ui-automation

I have been researching for sometime now on basically how to use a Wild Card profile for iPhone automation on a simulator.

> cloud devices providers like Amazon and Sauce Lab use this wild
>   card profile to make any app run on any iOS device

We have a team provision profile which is used to download and run builds on provisioned devices (from Hockey). I am looking for ways to basically run this build on a simulator (`for Appium automation, If I run the same build on a simulator it basically crashes on Launch and says Instruments crashed on start up` whatever research I have done till now points me to a wild card provisioning profile. I have no idea about it and looking for direction experienced people in the forum.

Comment: You don't need to code sign apps running on the simulator.  A wildcard provisioning profile would allow you to sign multiple apps for debugging purposes on physical devices.

Comment: So basically If an app built for phone need(published through Hockey) , how do I make run on Simulator?

Comment: Depending on how the ipa was built, you probably can't.  Typically apps built for devices (e.g. distribution through Hockey) are compiled with ARM architectures.  The Simulators use x86 architecture so they won't run.  It is possible to work out the supported architectures in the build settings, but I still do not believe you can run an app signed for device use on a Simulator.